# SQL Query to find max

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query that will list student(s) enrolled with the maximum total credit points.

```
SELECT q3.S_ID,
       q3.S_LAST,
       q3.S_FIRST,
      max( q3.Total Credits)
FROM
  (SELECT q2.S_ID,
          q2.S_LAST,
          q2.S_FIRST,
          sum(q1.CREDITS) Total Credits
   FROM
     (SELECT COURSE_NO,
             CREDITS
      FROM COURSE) q1
   JOIN
     (SELECT s.S_ID,
             s.S_LAST,
             s.S_FIRST,
             cs.COURSE_NO
      FROM STUDENT s
      JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON s.S_ID = e.S_ID
      JOIN COURSE_SECTION cs ON e.C_SEC_ID = cs.C_SEC_ID) q2 ON q1.COURSE_NO = q2.COURSE_NO
   GROUP BY q2.S_ID,
            q2.S_LAST,
            q2.S_FIRST) q3
GROUP BY q3.S_ID,
         q3.S_LAST,
         q3.S_FIRST;
```

But it doesn't work. This is the error I am getting:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 28 Column: 21
```

Could someone please help?

Thank you

Comment: I think there is the on clause missing for join q1 and q3.

Comment: Long line near the bottom, roughly in the middle. Took me a minute or two to spot all the aliases too.

Comment: I'm no expert here, but the `JOIN .. cs ON .. q2 ON ..` in line 21 seems wrong to me. Wouldn't those need to be split into two `JOIN` statements, or can you actually do that in SQL..?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure (no Oracle machine to test this) that your alias is the problem:

```
sum(q1.CREDITS) Total Credits
```

Should be

```
sum(q1.CREDITS) "Total Credits"
```

And therefore

```
max( q3.Total Credits)
```

Should be

```
max( q3."Total Credits")
```

But there may be more to it than that, as I say, I've no Oracle machine handy to test that out.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use spaces in column aliases

Comment: Well indeed! But some people have funny ideas about that for some reason. For my money, there's no good reason to use spaces in aliases or object names.

Comment: I've seen people use tools that are pretty basic to show the data that only displays the column name from the query.